# Sort list of numbers doesn't work with for loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of numbers:

```
list = [2, 5, 4, 1, 3]
```

I want to sort it and iterate sorted list using for loop:

```
print list
list.sort()
print list
for n in list:
    print list
    print n
    list.pop(0)
```

But the output doesn't look as expected:

```
# before sort:
[2, 5, 4, 1, 3]
# after sort:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
## still everything ok
# for loop:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
3
[3, 4, 5]
5
## what?
```

Why the for loop doesn't accept sorted list and works with the state before even though it returns the sorted list? Is there any hidden indexing, which `sort()` can't change? I'm new in Python and this is really weird behavior. What am I doing wrong?

What I want to achieve:

```
# before sort:
[2, 5, 4, 1, 3]
# after sort:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# for loop:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5
```

**Update:** I need that pop there. My full code of this function:

```
inTemplate = [False]
inLink = [False]
regexNeeded = [False, True]
# ...some if elif else skipped there
            # finds positions of brackets and sorts them
            brackets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("}}",text)]
            brackets += [m.start() for m in re.finditer("{{",text)]
            brackets += [m.start() for m in re.finditer("]]",text)]
            brackets += [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r"\[{2}",text)]
            brackets.sort(key=int)
            # if any bracket in text
            if not brackets == []:
                # for every bracket
                for n in brackets:
                    # what bracket and what starts/ends with it
                    if text[n] == '{':
                        inTemplate.append(True)
                    elif text[n] == '[':
                        inLink.append(True)
                    elif text[n] == ']':
                        inLink.pop()
                    else:
                        if inTemplate[-1]:
                            inTemplate.pop()
                        # if ends template which doesn't started, then there is no need to regex
                        elif regexNeeded[-1]:
                            regexNeeded.pop()
                        # break if out of regexNeeded area
                        else:
                            break
                    brackets.pop(0)
                # if for loop breaked
                if not brackets == []:
                    # do some regex on that bracket, where for loop breaked
                    where = brackets[0]
                    before = text[:where]
                    before = re.sub(r'\s*$', r'\n', before)
                    after = text[where:]
                    if not regexNeeded[-1]:
                        after = re.sub(r'^}}\s*', r'}}\n', after)
                    text = before + after
```

Comment: I think you just missed something in the output. It should work fine.

Comment: @cad Interesting to know what?

Comment: @aleskva then remove list.pop(0)

Comment: Why do you think you have a problem with sorting?

Comment: why do you need to pop

Comment: @juanchopanza The reason for that weird behavior. Others have rendered it irreproducible, though, so not so interesting anymore.

Comment: @Hooting I need to pop, because I have some complex if elif else inside the for loop, which processes the smaller lists and compares them with some predefined lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *pop* deletes an element in the list entirely. Therefore the reference is removed and we can only iterate over the amount of remaining items. The code is in Python 3, but I guess it shouldn't be too hard to change the print statements.

```
list = [2, 5, 4, 1, 3]

print(list)
list.sort()
print(list)
for n in range(len(list)):
    print(list)
    print(list.pop(0))
```

Comment: Looks as a good solution, but what if I want some `if listItem == 21:` inside for loop? (if the list would be bigger)

Comment: just use list[n] == 21 @aleskva

Answer (score 1):

The function `pop()` will **remove** and return the *last* item you have in the list, in index `len(list)-1`. Calling `pop(0)` **removes** the *first* item, so if you repeatedly call it then your list will be printed *in-order*, meaning `1, 2, 3, 4 ,5` since you sorted it first.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) please:

```
list.pop([i])
```

> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it.

If you *don't* want the items of the list to be removed, but just print them, you can use `print (list[index])` instead of `pop()`. And in your loop, since it's sorted and started from 1, you can actually use `print(list[n-1])` even.

Comment: I know, what it does, but I need it there. I have more complex code. See my comment under question. Do you know, how to solve this with pop still there?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? you can use pop(0) and it will work as you want it to.

Comment: I need to pop, because I have some complex if elif else inside the for loop, which processes the smaller lists and compares them with some predefined lists. So I need to compare smaller list, but still iterate the original one.

Comment: You will have to attach a *complete* example (also minimal and verifiable). Please edit your question with **all** the details, and then you might get it re-opened with enough votes (I will vote if it's clear). And then I could help you further :)

Comment: And I added some comments to code